# How to localize or delete message "Please fill out this field." on AWS Cognito login page created by AWS Amplify Vue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Now I'm try to localize AWS Cognito Login Page created by AWS Amplify Vue.
But I still can't localize or delete pop-up massage that appears when input is empty.
This seems not to be api request/response, so even though I tried `I18n` with `Please fill out this field`, it does not change.

```
<template>
  <amplify-authenticator>
    <amplify-sign-in slot="sign-in" hide-sign-up="true"></amplify-sign-in>
  </amplify-authenticator>
</template>
```

```js
export const extraVocabularies = {
  'ja-JP': {
    'Please fill out this field.':
      'hoge fuga',
  },
};
I18n.putVocabularies(extraVocabularies);
I18n.setLanguage('ja-JP');
```

[image]
So Please give me the way to localize or delete this message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the message `"Please fill out this field"` is generated by browser. 
So depending on locale of browser, the locale of this message also changes.